# Desktop shortcut shows some configuration wizard on double click

Tags: winforms, installation, projects

I made a setup project for my windows forms application and then installed it. It properly created a shortcut on desktop. Now when I double click it to open, it shows a progress bar like thing saying Configuring application. After that, my windows form appears and runs normally.

I have no clue why this is happening. My earlier version for the same application was running properly with o. Also if I install the previous version, it starts normally without any problems. Only the setup files that I am creating now are showing this problem.

Any one having any clue...

Comment: And this is a problem... why? It could be runtime doing its things.

Comment: It is annoying for the end user. Also it shows every time I try to open it..

Answer (score 1):

You created a [ClickOnce installation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31kztyey.aspx).  You probably wanted to create a standard [Setup Project.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19x10e5c.aspx)  IIRC, there was some issue with this type of project in Visual Studio 2010, as in the project type is being depreciated, but I can't seem to find anything about that now.

Other alternatives are using [WiX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/) or the limited edition of [InstallShield](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/deployment_technologies/archive/2010/04/20/installshield-limited-edition-is-available-for-download-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx).

Oddly enough, the ClickOnce installer is pretty good, assuming you have the infrastructure to support it (a spot on the web where you place updates) and don't mind the nonstandard behavior (that weird dialog on start).  Frankly, installer technologies right now in the .NET world suck.  They're all extremely complicated and fail to insulate the developer from the intricacies of how installers work with Windows.

---

To turn off ClickOnce, IIRC, do the following:

- Uncheck "Sign the ClickOnce manifests" on the Signing tab

[image: Manifests]

- Uncheck "Enable ClickOnce security settings" from the security tab

[image: Security settings]

- remove any references to "System.Deployment" from your projects

Comment: Actually I intend to create a normal setup project. I tried my hands with ClickOnce Installation, but rejected the idea when I came to know that we can't create our desired folder structure in clickonce application. I suspect that my attempt to create this clickonce application may have resulted in some settings change and the problem arising...but I could not track what the problem was. I am still trying to find a solution.

Comment: Thnx..Will for your sincere help. I checked all above and the first two options were proper. I tried with your third point and got no positive result. But one thing I discovered that the problem is with my own system only. I tried on another machine and everything is proper. Now I need to know the problems with my machine...I have to see...thnx again